# Запятая после "вообще" (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, вводные-слова, наречия

Меня спрашивают: "какой вариант верный?" Я говорю: "Вообще(,) первый, но я сомневаюсь". Нужна ли запятая после *вообще*? Мне сложно понять, является ли тут оно вводным словом или нет. Вроде смысл вводного слова, но интонационно никаких пауз нет и выделять себя оно как-то не просит. Помогите, пожалуйста, прояснить ситуацию!

А если части, начинающейся с *но*, и вовсе нет? Изменится ли пунктуация в этом случае? Заранее благодарю!!!

Comment: Подобрать бы здесь более аккуратный (стилистически) пример, вопрос превратился бы в настоящую головоломку, не имеющую однозначного ответа.

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ второй**

Я использовала **интонационный анализ,** и у меня получилось два решения. **Просто послушала, как я произношу эту фразу.** Мы обычно  выделяем вводные слова не паузами, как это считается, а ударением.

(1) *Какой вариант верный? –  **ВообщЕ** (вообщЕ-то), **пЕрвый**, но я пока сомневаюсь*.

(2) *Какой вариант верный? –  Вообще-то **пЕрвый**, но я пока сомневаюсь*.

**Пояснение**

**1. Какое значение имеет вводное слово «вообще»**

Вводные слова выражают **отношение** говорящего к содержанию речи, а не само содержание. Вот и надо понять, **что это за отношение.** Я думаю, что вводное слово «вообще»  –  это **особая метка неуверенности**. Слово «общий» имеет 10 значений, и среди них есть такие: 8. Касающийся лишь главного, основного, не затрагивающий частностей, конкретных деталей. 10. Неглубокий, поверхностный, лишённый конкретности; схематичный.

Действительно, такая общая оценка не может быть окончательной. Мы часто стали употреблять в речи это слово, и, возможно, оно как-то определяет общественное сознание на современном этапе. Так что можете ради интереса проследить за собственной речью и дать оценку своему душевному состоянию.

**2. Чем отличаются приведенные выше фразы?**

В первом случае выделенное ударением вводное слово **уже задает тему неуверенности,** а вторая часть эту тему еще раз подтверждает (получается такая **неуверенность в квадрате**). Во втором случае  вводное слово теряет ударение и становится частицей, основное внимание говорящий уделяет слову **«первый»,** подчеркивая его ударением. **Именно это слышит и его собеседник,** не более того (стоит об этом задуматься, когда мы читаем словарную статью о значении вводного слова).

Наличие **вариантов** в данном предложении привело к взаимному непониманию при обсуждении вопроса. Иногда структура предложения позволяет использовать только **один вариант**, и  тогда он однозначно определяется в речи.

**3. О вводных словах «вообще, вообще-то, вообще говоря»**

Слово **«вообще-то»** может быть вводным словом и не будет отличаться от вводного слова **«вообще»,** если вы выделите его ударением. А если не будете выделять, то на его основе строится фраза с противопоставлением.

Что касается сочетания **«вообще говоря»**, то ему в данной  фразе не место. Это другая метка со значением «обобщая частные детали».  Хотите сказать: «Вообще говоря, первый, но я пока сомневаюсь»?   По-моему, звучит не лучшим образом, говорит о непонимании значения слов. Также использование этого слова **для проверки**  только уводит вас от правильного решения.

**4. Вывод**

Тема вводных слов считается сложной, но, может быть, это **искусственная сложность?**  Может быть, просто неверное понимание их природы,  некорректная формулировка правил? В любом случае лично я буду использовать **интонационное решение**, а подобрать к  уже готовому ответу нужное правило труда не составит.

Comment: Ну и где правило найти? Стараешься тут, а всё как об стенку горох.

Comment: Артем,  вот вы считаете, что это вводное слово. Если вы это слышите, то есть выделяете его ударением в речи, то это действительно вводное слово. В этом случае оно выражает отношение к сказанному или используется для оформления речи. Если выражает отношение, то какое именно? Все эти вопросы вы решаете для СЕБЯ, чтобы убедиться в правильности своего выбора. Но если требуется ФОРМАЛЬНОЕ обоснование, то  подойдет смысл "вообще говоря", так как других правил у нас нет, а все указывают на это дежурное сочетание.

Comment: Начнём с того, что я совсем так не считаю. Просто хочу найти авторитетный источник, который бы рассматривал "вообще-то", как вы, не вводным. Просто я ответ давал, исходя из того, что нашёл на Грамоте, но мне он самому не нравится. И кроме того, я рассматривал "вообще" Игоря, у него НЕ "вообще-то", а это меняет дело, интонация ведь другая.

Comment: Во втором ответе я рассматриваю два варианта,  причем слово "вообще" считаю вводным, так как выделяю. его ударением, другое произношение для меня неудобно. А вы как произносите это предложение, используете ли это слово в своей речи, какое значение в него  вкладываете? Это же интересно понять, а не только авторитетные источники искать. Или вы так не считаете?

Comment: Вообще, согласен с вами в целом во всём, в том числе и что оно может быть и вводным, как у меня сейчас, и невводным (вообще-то) и насчёт ударений. Хочется только, чтобы где-то были хоть отчасти такие же мысли. Не на каких-то непонятных сайтах, а у признанных авторов.

Comment: Представьте себе, что всеми признанный автор в чем-то заблуждается, но авторитет его так велик, что люди верят  ему безоговорочно. Кто-то догадывается об ошибке,  даже говорит об этом вслух, но таким людям не доверяет никто. Ни у кого не хватает смелости усомниться в истинности мнения великого человека. Так что, Артем, ждать новой теории вводных слов вам, возможно, придется долго,  лет так тысячу примерно. Точно такая история произошла с Аристотелем. http://interesnyjfakt.ru/rasprostranyonnye-zabluzhdeniya-uchyonyx-proshlogo/

Comment: И вот если у вас нет в запасе такого количества времени, то вы можете уже сейчас воспользоваться своими мыслями.  Истинность теории проверяется практикой, и вот я не вижу, чтобы она подтверждала существующую теорию. Значит, она несовершенна и поэтому нуждается в доработке.

Comment: Гениальные мысли!!

Comment: Спасибо! Вообще-то я обычно стараюсь обходиться чужими гениальными мыслями, если только совсем ничего подходящего нет.  Например, в ту же тему: «Идеи обычно опережают свое время, пылятся на полках и обретают вторую жизнь, когда  созревают общественные условия для их реализации». Общественное сознание, ты уже готово?  –  Нет, конечно – откуда. Так что придется пока подождать.

Comment: Человеческое мышление вообще лениво по своей природе, и его непременно нужно чем-либо подстегивать – яркими эмоциями, необходимостью в решении проблемы и т.д. В качестве примера – мой недавний вопрос о правилах Розенталя. Там приводятся два варианта оформления – и ничего не объясняется! К тому же один из примеров не соответствует литературному источнику, а мне нужно срочно разобрать тему. Вот вам и мотивация для «гениальных» мыслей.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, поскольку здесь "вообще" имеет смысл "вообще говоря". И это вводное слово. Если убрать вторую часть, запятая всё равно будет нужна. Другое дело, не очень понятно, какой смысл вкладывается тогда в "вообще" при отсутствии противопоставления.

Comment: При отсутствии противопоставления "вообще" может означать "в большинстве случаев". Тогда запятая не нужна. **Вообще-то** с противопоставлением тоже всё не так просто, **но** стилистика с вводным "вообще" тогда наименее корявая (по сравнению с другими вариантами), поэтому соглашусь.

Comment: В предложении выше я специально выделил противопоставление с союзом (или, по другим источникам, частицей) "вообще" без запятой.

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не понимаю, когда при значении "в большинстве случаев" (я его вообще не чувствую) нельзя применить также и "вообще говоря". На Грамоте [вот](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_89) я не вижу разницы между примером с обособлением и без.

Answer (score 1):

В данной ситуации я считаю верным такой ответ:  ***Вообще-то пЕрвый, но я сомневАюсь.*** Без второй части предложение не имеет смысла.

**Семантику** фразы я понимаю так:  по **общим** признакам первый ответ  ближе к истине, и я выбираю его.  Но я в этом не уверен, может быть, я не учитываю какие-то  **частные** детали.

Таким образом, здесь имеет место **противопоставление общего и частного,** что выражается словом «вообще-то».

**В этой теме** (общее и частное) можно выделить  **две ситуации**: (1) **ПЕРЕХОД** от частных деталей  к общей оценке (или наоборот);   (в) **ПРОТИВОПОСТАВЛЕНИЕ** общего и частного.

**В первой ситуации** используются **вводные слова** «вообще говоря, вообще, вообще-то» со значением **«обобщая детали, говоря в целом».**

**Во второй ситуации**  используется слово "вообще-то" со значением **противопоставления** (при наличии противительных союзов), которое также не отделяется запятой. К этой же ситуации можно отнести наречие "вообще" в составе словосочетания (говорить о Болгарии вообще), там тема противопоставления просматривается в неявном виде.

Но я не вижу в приведенном примере обобщения чего-либо, поэтому это не вводное слово.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ! Действительно, случай непростой. Без второй части в слово "вообще" я лично вкладываю смысл "исходя из моих знаний, на мой взгляд". Кто мне все же мешает это слово так воспринимать?

Comment: Вы же даете ответ другим, а не себе. Фраза кажется незаконченной, слушатели будут ждать пояснений. Если сказать "ну, первый" или "допустим, первый", то ответ выглядит законченным, объяснения не предвидятся.

Comment: Ну где об этом говорится? Хочется найти хороший источник. Вместо (в) 2?

Comment: Я тоже хочу без запятой, но не вижу нормального источника. А главное, у Игоря было просто "вообще", без "то".